# Gwt combobox compare use contains instead of startswith

Tags: java, combobox, gxt

Need to create a Combobox using GWT in Java. This combobox must have the typeahead function and also must use "contains" instead of "startswith" for suggestions. Any idea of how to implement this? Should I have to override something?
Thanks in advance

---Edit added some parts of my code
First I'm declaring the combobox and a store

```
private ComboBox docTypeField;
private Store store;
```

Then I'm initialazing the combobox in this way

```
docTypeField = new ComboBox();
docTypeField.setFieldLabel("Doc Types:");
docTypeField.setDisplayField(DocTypePicker.STORE_FIELD_NAME);
docTypeField.setMode(ComboBox.LOCAL);
docTypeField.setStore(store);
docTypeField.setTypeAhead(true);
```

I have tried to modify the filter by method in the store but it didn't work as expected

```
store.filterBy(new StoreTraversalCallback() {
            public boolean execute(Record record) {
                //if user text matches the name or alias then its true
                if (sugestDocttype.getValue() == null
                        || sugestDocttype.getValue().length() == 0
                        || (record.getAsString(DocTypePicker.STORE_FIELD_NAME) != null && record.getAsString(
                                DocTypePicker.STORE_FIELD_NAME).toUpperCase().contains(
                                        sugestDocttype.getValue().toUpperCase()))
                        ){ 

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: So far what you have tried ??Can you please show us your workaround ?

Comment: I hace tried to use a suggestbox instead of the combobox, however it doesn't have the typeahead option

Comment: What he meant by "what have you tried" is "Can you please provide pieces of your code (with the problems that happen) so we can help you fix it?"

Comment: Just added my code. Thanks  in advance for the help provided

Answer (score 0):

May be it helps you: [Creating a Multi-Valued Auto-Complete Field Using GWT SuggestBox and REST](http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/gwt-rest-auto/).

Comment: I tried to use suggest box, the problem with suggestbox is that it doesn't have the typeahead option